# query parameter in url not work in angular

Tags: angular, routes

when i use query parameter in my URL, i get below error :

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/instagram/overview%3Fcode%3D7a6e5944cae649248dfad5509d8e6e67'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/instagram/overview%3Fcode%3D7a6e5944cae649248dfad5509d8e6e67'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)

this is my routing :

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {InstagramComponent} from './instagram.component';
import {InstagramAnalysisComponent} from './instagram-analysis   /instagram-analysis.component';

const instagramRoutes: Routes = [
  {
path: '', component: InstagramComponent,
children: [
  {path: 'overview', loadChildren: './instagram-overview/io.module#IoModule'},
  {path: 'content-production', loadChildren: './instagram-content/instagram-content-production/icp.module#IcpModule'},
  {path: 'all-content', loadChildren: './instagram-content/instagram-all-content/iac.module#IacModule'},
  {path: 'analyz', component: InstagramAnalysisComponent},
  {path: 'create/addig', loadChildren: './add-instagram/add-ig.module#AddIgModule'},
]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
RouterModule.forChild(instagramRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
   ]
})
export class InstagramRoutingModule {
}
```

i expect below URL work correctly , but that not work:
        http://localhost:4200/home/instagram/create/addig?code=7a6e5944cae649248dfad5509d8e6e67

what i must do in my routing to fix this ?

Comment: How are you navigating/ creating your route.. If it is done using a function, try to log the url created before navigating

Comment: @SachinGupta this URL : http://localhost:4200/home/instagram/create/addig
work properly but when i attach query parameter to this, not work

Comment: How are you adding query params.. Make sure you are not `URL-encoding` the string. The URL in the question looks like `?` has been converted to `%3F` and `=` converted to `%3D`.

Comment: any solution to this problem ? please post I am also facing the similar issue or can you please post some reference url from where I can read about the same.